# Java - how do I iterate through this map so method my method returns a string

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a method like this:

```
public static String m(String key1, String value1,  String key2, String value2) {

    return "{ "
            + " \"SomeAttribute\": "
            + "{"
            + "\"" + key1 + "\": \"" + value1 + ","
            + "\"" + key2 + "\": \"" + value2
            + "\"}"
            + "}";
}
```

I want to change it so that it accepts a map  as a paramereter instead of Strings. I tried this approach but  I am getting confuse with the synaxt as there are too many + and "":

```
public static String m(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();

    return "{ "
            + " \"SomeAttribute\": "
            + "{"
            +
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        "\"" + pair.getKey(); + "\": pair.getValue();
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException


        +"\"}"
                + "}";
    }
```

Please can someone show me how to fix this code?

Comment: `List` usage seems more appropriate than `Map`, in your case.

Comment: Add an example! What is the output? What do you expect?  What is the problem.

Comment: Creating JSON data by string concatenation is IMHO a bad idea. Use a proper JSON library instead.

Comment: Don't generate JSON by hand. Use a JSON parser/marshaller. There are plenty of them. And they will all generate valid JSON, whereas your code won't in some cases.

Comment: thanks @boobalangnanasekaran, can you show me how would you do it by using List?

Comment: thanks @Robert, what if I want to learn by not using a JSON library? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop won't return the String you want this way, you need to create the String and, at every loop, concatenate a new one to it:

```
public static String m(Map<String, String> mp)
{
   Iterator<?> it = mp.entrySet().iterator();

   String str = "{"
      + " \"SomeAttribute\": "
      + "{";

   while (it.hasNext())
   {
      Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
      str += "\"" + pair.getKey() + "\": \"" + pair.getValue() + "\",";
   }

   str += "}"
      + "}";

   return str;    
}
```

If you don't want to use `while`, you can use `for`, too:

```
public static String m(Map<String, String> mp)
{
   String str = "{"
      + " \"SomeAttribute\": "
      + "{";

   for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : mp.entrySet())
   {
      str += "\"" + pair.getKey() + "\": \"" + pair.getValue() + "\",";
   }

   str += "}"
      + "}";

   return str;
}
```